# Check if file is empty

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file, size

I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this, but I don't remember any.

How can I check if a certain file is empty with Objective-C? Preferably without loading its contents (just in case the file isn't empty).

I thought about `[[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: PATH] length]` but that loads the entire file just to know how big it is. Isn't there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "empty" you mean it has absolutely nothing in it (0 bytes) you could do something like this:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    unsigned long long size = [attributes fileSize];
    if (attributes && size == 0) {
        // file exists, but is empty.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.